# (PowerShell) Why is this regular expression so slow for the given input?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have written this PowerShell snippet:

```
$signature = "//    Sub SetParameters(parameterHere,parameterThere,p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6,p7,p8,p9,p10, p11,p12)"

$pattern = "^//\t[a-zA-Z]+ [\w\-]+\(([\w\-]+)(,*[\w\-]+)*\)"

if($signature -match $pattern){
    Write-Output "Signature matches the pattern"
}
else{
    Write-Output "Signature does not match the pattern"
}
```

Normally, the code above should output the line below, since, if you look closely, there is a space after `p10,`:

```
Signature does not match the pattern
```

However, my regex check is really, really slow for the given input. On the other hand, if the signature actually matches the pattern, the code quickly outputs:

```
Signature matches the pattern
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Because of `(,*[\w\-]+)*` pattern that causes catastrophic backtracking. I explained this type of problem [in my video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4-nrlRF5xX0). TLDR: remove `*` after `,`.